# sort rows according to cell values

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to get the entire row of A that has less than or equal to 50 values and sort it to column B. How do I do this I tried the addConditionalFormatRule of sheetsbatchupdate but I there's no method to sort the rows also how do i get selected grid date as response here is my request

```
{
          requests:[{
            addConditionalFormatRule: {
              rule:{
                booleanRule:{ 
                  condition:{
                    values:[{
                      userEnteredValue:'50',
                    }],
                    type: 'NUMBER_LESS_THAN_EQ',

                  },
                  format:{
                    backgroundColor:{
                      green: 2
                    }
                  }
                },
                ranges:[{
                  sheetId: {correct_sheetid},
                  startRowIndex: 1,
                  startColumnIndex: 1,
                  endColumnIndex: 2
                }]
              },
              index: 0
            }
          }],
          includeSpreadsheetInResponse: true,
          responseIncludeGridData: true,

        };
```

when I query this using the [google sheets services](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_GB#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate) it doesn't return any information of the grid date being updated

Comment: Does your request work on the Google APIs Explorer website? It is very unclear what you mean when you say you want to *sort* a "whole *row* of A" into *column B*.

Comment: here is the instruction when doing it manually : Highlight all rows with 50% or more in column A, and sort by 'Data', Sort Range', 'Sort Sheet By Column B, sort it in DESCENDING order'.